# Confused about linq this query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have an xml file like this.

```
<Accounts>
    <Account Id="">
        <UserName/>
        <Password/>
        <AddingDate/>
        <AccountType/>
    </Account>
</Accounts>
```

What I want to do is that if the first element's  attaribute value  is not empty return true otherwise false

```
private bool IsListEmpty(){    
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("UserAccounts.xml");

    var c = from p in doc.Descendants("Account") 
            where p.Element("Id").Value == "" 
            select p.Value;

    if(c==null)return......
}
```

But I  am stuck.How can I do this

Comment: "Stuck" is not a proper problem description. Explain in detail what you are expecting, what is actually happening and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: How do you create accounts without IDs?

Comment: You are confusing attributes and elements. Your program tries to get an element named `Id` inside element named `Account`, but it's an attribute. Try something like this:
`where (string)p.attribute("Id") == "" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `FirstOrDefault()` on your LINQ and then check if Id attribute is empty:

```
var account = doc.Descendants("Account").FirstOrDefault();
return account != null &&  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(account.Attribute("Id").Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly but I think that .Any would do the trick.

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("UserAccounts.xml");
return xelement.Elements("Account").Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)x.Element("Id"))).Any();
```

Any will return true if one element is found that is ""

Comment: but that is not the question. he/she wanted to kow if the Id of the first entry is empty or not, not if there is any entry with a non-empty id